# Disable absolute volume in bluetooth audio

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth

When changing the volume of a bluetooth output in macOS, it sends those signals to the bluetooth device which then adjusts its internal volume.

I would like it to lower the volume in software like it does for regular outputs however; keeping the bluetooth device's internal volume where it is.

Android has a "Disable absolute volume" developer option which achieves precisely that. Does macOS have an equivalent?

I have checked Bluetooth Explorer.app for a setting but couldn't find anything.

Comment: To what end? The audio standard for gain-staging is the keep high signal at the point of greatest potential noise & attenuate at the end point. Bluetooth, being inherently noisy, would seem to benefit from this strategy.

Comment: The problem is how fine-grained the controls are. There are very few steps in the headset's internal volume management which means I get the choice between a level that's too loud and one that's too quiet when changing volume. In software, you can have arbitrarily many steps for controlling volume. It works just like I want it to on Android, I just need the mac to do the same.

Comment: Another issue that could at least be worked around without absolute volume: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432404/minimum-bluetooth-headset-volume-is-too-high-in-teams-calls-on-macos