# minimum bluetooth headset volume is too high in Teams calls on macOS

Tags: macos, bluetooth, sound-volume, ms-teams

I've got a pair of Epos Adapt 660s connected to macOS Monterey and, whenever I'm in a Teams call, the volume level is near uncomfortable (depending on the others' individual volumes).

Problem is: The volume slider is already at the minimum.

Volume level outside of calls seems fine (Teams' own ringer for example) but macOS seems to switch to a different volume setup when in a Teams call.

How can I get Teams calls volume to a comfortable level?

I don't remember this happening on macOS Big Sur or at least not to this degree.

Comment: Which volume slider? On the headphones or in system prefs?

Comment: I was talking about the system one but macOS actually synchronises them. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429159/disable-absolute-volume-in-bluetooth-audio for more ways why that's detrimental.