# How do I make fine-grain volume adjustments to Bluetooth audio in macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, sound-volume

No, my question is not a duplicate of ["Is fine volume adjustment possible in macOS?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19146/is-fine-volume-adjustment-possible-in-macos). Fine volume adjustments are working in macOS Monterey, ***just not for any Bluetooth devices***. Edit: my question might be related to "[Disable absolute volume in bluetooth audio](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429159/disable-absolute-volume-in-bluetooth-audio)"...

Steps to reproduce:

- get a Mac running macOS Monterey
- connect a pair of Bluetooth headphones
- open any application and start playing audio
- perform a "fine-grain" volume adjustment up or down by pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>volume key</kbd> (this will make the system volume go up or down by 1/4 of a full "notch" in the volume bar)

Expected result:

- the Bluetooth device's volume increases or decreases by 1/4 of one "notch" in the volume bar

Actual result:

- the volume stays exactly the same until you've performed four consecutive "fine-grain" adjustments (equalling one "notch"), at which point the volume jumps by one full "notch"

Really hoping that there's a fix for this, because volume "6" on my Bluetooth headphones is too quiet, whereas "7" is too loud.